# Overlay Div disappears after Javascript function completes

Tags: javascript, html, css

First off, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ribbs2521/Q7C3m/1/

I thought I could run JS on fiddle but it's not working, either way all of my code is on there so I think we should be good.

So, I am trying to create my own custom image viewer which was working great until I tried to implement PREV and NEXT (in the fiddle they are text but they're actually images).  I click next and it changes the picture in the viewer but then my overlay div disappears.

The reason I know it actually changes the picture is because if I put an alert at the end of prevImage() and/or nextImage() I see the changed picture, but once I click OK it all disappears.

I don't know what is going on. I am not sure if it's my JS or CSS causing the issue, I am fairly new to JS, CSS and HTML.

Can anyone tell me why my div disappears after this function is performed?

Here is the JS:

```
var images = Array();
var cursor = 0;

function showHide(obj) {
    alert("Working");
    var overlay = document.getElementById("ImgOverlay");
    if (obj instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
        // Get list of images in gallery
        var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
        images = gallery.getElementsByTagName("img");
        cursor = -1;
        while (images[++cursor].src != obj.src) {}

        // Show the image
        putImageInViewer(obj);
        overlay.style.display = "block";

    } else if (overlay.style.display !== "none" && overlay.style.display !== "") { // If it's the div that you clicked...
        hideElement(overlay);
    }
}

function hideElement(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
}

function putImageInViewer(obj) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = obj.src;
    var size = 600;
    var h = img.height;
    var w = img.width;
    // We want a max size of 600 but don't want to blow images up (bad graphics)
    // Images should be their actual size but limited to 600px MAX
    if (h <= 600 && w <= 600) {
        if (h > w) {
            size = h;
        } else {
            size = w;
        }
    }
    if (h > w) {
        document.getElementById("overlay-img").innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + img.src + "\" height=\"" + size + "\">";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("overlay-img").innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + img.src + "\" width=\"" + size + "\">";
    }
}

function nextImage() {
    // Check if we need to loop around
    if (cursor < images.length) {
        cursor++;
    } else {
        cursor = 0;
    }
    putImageInViewer(images[cursor]);
}

function prevImage() {
    // Check if we need to loop around
    if (cursor > 0) {
        cursor--;
    } else {
        cursor = images.length;
    }
    putImageInViewer(images[cursor]);
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrap li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:240px;
    height:240px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap li div {
    position:absolute;
    height:0;
    width:220px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#fff;
    transition:height 1s;
}
#wrap li:hover div {
    height:50px;
}
#wrap li img {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ImgOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /*fallback*/
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /*background-image:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;*/
    display: none;
}
#imgnav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 38%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15px 0 0 -363px;
    width: 730px;
    height: 60px;
}
#overlay-img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
#overlay-img img {
    border: 2px solid white;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And finally, the HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h1>An Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
            <img src="w" onclick="showHide(this);">
            <div>Image 1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="w" onclick="showHide(this);">
            <div>Image 2</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- For Image Viewer -->
<div id="ImgOverlay" onclick="showHide(this);">
    <div id="imgnav"> <span style="color: white; cursor: pointer; float: left" height="60px" width="60px" onclick="prevImage();">PREV</span>
        <div id="overlay-img">
            <!-- Image will go here -->
        </div>  <span style="color: white; cursor: pointer; float: left" height="60px" width="60px" onclick="prevImage();">NEXT</span>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Image Viewer -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running into JavaScript [event propagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).  In a nutshell, events that fire on DOM elements (such as the "click" event on your "PREV" and "NEXT" buttons), bubble up the DOM, firing again on each of the original element's parents.  In your case, this means that when you click your "NEXT" button, it fires `prevImage()` and then when the event bubbles up to `ImgOverlay`, it fires `showHide(this)`.

You need to modify your event handlers to tell the browser not to propagate the event.  Change your button markup to something like the following:

```
<span id="nextButton" style="color: white; cursor: pointer; float: left" height="60px" width="60px">NEXT</span>
```

Then use the following to handle the click event:

```
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
nextButton.onclick = function (ev) {
  nextImage();

  if (!ev) {
    // Old versions of Internet Explorer do not pass the event to handlers.
    ev = window.event;
  }
  ev.cancelBubble = true;
  if (ev.stopPropagation) {
    // W3C standard, works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.
    ev.stopPropagation();
  }
};
```

Comment: I figured it was probably some weird thing you wouldn't just know from reading tutorials.  Anyway, I altered my code as you suggested but it isn't triggering the nextButton.onclick() when I click the button.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work.  What I did was I kept the onclick on the button but I passed the event to the nextImage() method and killed propagation there.  Thanks for the super fast response!